# Dynamically returning the inherited class type in a inherited class method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have a class

```
class Node {
   children: Node[];
}
```

which is inherited by several other classes

```
class Block extends Node {
  // ...
}
```

In all inherited classes I wish to have a function called replaceChild:

```
const block = new Block();
block.replaceChild(oldChild, newChild);
```

I do not want to implement this function in all inherited classes (duh!). The clue here though is that my classes are immutable, so instead of mutating the class I want to return a new instance with the changed `children`. The thing is, the function `replaceChild`, which I want to implement in `Node` should not return  a `Node` instance, but an instance of the inherited class:

```
class Node {
  children: Node[];
  replaceChild(oldChild, newChild): Node {
    // ...
    return new Node(/* ... */)
  }
}

class Block extends Node {
  // ...
}

const block = new Block();
const newMutatedBlock: Block = block.replaceChild(oldChild, newChild);
```

and I am using `TypeScript`. How can I tell TypeScript (without typecasting each time) that the method `replaceChild` on a `Block` node returns a `Block` instead of a `Node`?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), a type which corresponds to the `this` object.  Instead of saying `replaceChild()` returns the type `Node`, you say it returns the type `this`.

Note that you can't just call `new Node()` in the implementation of `replaceChild()`, since that will not create your subclasses correctly.  Luckily, instances of classes hold a reference to their constructor, so you can call `new this.constructor()`.  Unluckily, TypeScript doesn't know anything about `this.constructor` other than it's a `Function`.  Luckily, you can declare that `this.constructor` has the type `new()=>this` and use it safely.  (It's up to you to declare the argument types correctly and ensure that all subclass constructors take the same argument types).  Here's how it looks:

```
class Node {
    children: Node[];
    "constructor": new (/* ... */) => this;
    replaceChild(oldChild, newChild): this {
        // ...
        return new this.constructor(/* ... */)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the `oldChild` and `newChild` are also supposed to be `this`, or `Node`, or what.  You have to decide that.

And now the test:

```
class Block extends Node {
    // ...
}

const block = new Block();
const newMutatedBlock: Block = block.replaceChild(oldChild, newChild);
```

That works (assuming `oldChild` and `newChild` exist and are the right type), since `Block.replaceChild()` returns a `Block` instead of just a `Node`.

See it working in [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Node%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20children%3A%20Node%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22constructor%22%3A%20new%20%28%2F%2A%20...%20%2A%2F%29%20%3D%3E%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20replaceChild%28oldChild%3A%20Node%2C%20newChild%3A%20Node%29%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.constructor%28%2F%2A%20...%20%2A%2F%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Block%20extends%20Node%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20block%20%3D%20new%20Block%28%29%3B%0D%0Aconst%20oldChild%20%3D%20new%20Node%28%29%3B%0D%0Ablock.children.push%28oldChild%29%3B%0D%0Aconst%20newChild%20%3D%20new%20Node%28%29%3B%0D%0Aconst%20newMutatedBlock%3A%20Block%20%3D%20block.replaceChild%28oldChild%2C%20newChild%29%3B%0D%0A)

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to un-accept, if I do `return new this.constructor ` I get `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error; did you remember the line `"constructor": new (/* ... */) => this;` from above?  Can you link me to an error in the Playground or something?